# Trouble understanding .indexOf in this code problem

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I recently completed this Leetcode assessment for an open-book interview. Luckily I was able to Google for help, and passed the assessment. I'm having trouble understanding what exactly is happening on the line declared below. I'd love it if one of your smartypants could help me understand it better!

Thank you!

**The problem:**

Have the function NonrepeatingCharacter(str) take the str parameter being passed, which will contain only alphabetic characters and spaces, and return the first non-repeating character. For example: if str is "agettkgaeee" then your program should return k. The string will always contain at least one character and there will always be at least one non-repeating character.

Once your function is working, take the final output string and combine it with your ChallengeToken, both in reverse order and separated by a colon.

Your ChallengeToken: iuhocl0dab7

```
function SearchingChallenge(str) { 
 
  // global token variable
  let token = "iuhocl0dab7"

  // turn str into array with .split()
  let arrayToken = token.split('')

  // reverse token
  let reverseArrayToken = arrayToken.reverse();
 
  // loop over str 
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    // c returns each letter of the string we pass through
    let c = str.charAt(i);

    ***--------------WHAT IS THIS LINE DOING?-------------***
    if (str.indexOf(c) == i && str.indexOf(c, i + 1) == -1) {

      // create variable, setting it to array with first repeating character in it
      let arrayChar = c.split()

      // push colon to array
      arrayChar.push(':')

      // push reversed token to array
      arrayChar.push(reverseArrayToken)

      // flatten array with .flat() as the nested array is only one level deep
      let flattenedArray = arrayChar.flat()

      // turns elements of array back to string
      let joinedArray = flattenedArray.join('')

      return joinedArray;
    }
  }
 
};
```

Comment: it's checking to see that a character occurs only at the current index and not at any later index. I think also that it's a bad solution.

Comment: Please verify the tag descriptions. `dsa` is unrelated to your question.

Comment: @trincot Apologies, I thought all Leetcode-esk questions were considered DSA

Comment: @Pointy I'd be curious to see how you'd go about this problem. Feel free to share :-)

Comment: Digital Signature Algorithm? I don't think so. A few years ago someone thought it a good idea to use DSA for Data Structures and Algorithms, but that is not what `dsa` is about here. There are `data-structures` and `algorithms` tags.

Comment: @trincot Haha, I see what happened there. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Pointy is right. However, I have a question. Could you tell me why you think it's bad solution, @Pointy?

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do is:

1. Reduce the string to an object, where the keys are the letters and the values are objects containing counts of occurrences and initial index in the string
2. Sort the `.values()` of that object in order of minimum count and minimum index
3. Use the first entry in the result of the sort to return the character

So something like

```
function firstUnique(str) {
  const counts = Array.from(str).reduce((acc, c, i) => {
    (acc[c] || (acc[c] = { c, count: 0, index: i })).count++;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return Object.values(counts).sort((c1, c2) =>
    c1.count - c2.count || c1.index - c2.index
  )[0].c;
}
```